Resource to learn about topological defects
I am a physics PhD student. What are some resources to learn about topological defects in condensed matter theory, quantum field theory, and other contexts? I particularly welcome resources that are more mathematical than physical.
I am aware of Mermin's RevModPhys "The topological theory of defects in ordered media". I find that this review spends a huge amount of time introducing textbook homotopy/group theory as opposed to talking about topological defects. I would prefer a resource which does not do this.

A quick search leads to some excellent online matetials already incorporated into syllabus' such as this one at Stony Brook
A quick search yields several resources for self study such as what is found through Academia.edu
The specific reference you mention by Mermin is also freely available at APS.
Arxiv is still a great resource and a quick search yields decent introductions.
